# Room search query

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

when I want to search for a user in my database using room query, I have to enter the full name to get the result. How can I search in database letter by letter?

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE name LIKE :search")
    fun find(search:String?):List<User>
```

Comment: read about textwatchers

Comment: you can use % wildcard

Comment: Hi , could you explain me how to search for a user in my database using room query:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64850505/how-to-read-databaseroom-and-display-a-textview/64921006#64921006

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE name LIKE :search")
fun find(search:String?):List<User>

search = "%Kourosh%";
find(search);

//OR

@Query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE name LIKE '%' || : arg0 || '%'")
fun find(search:String?):List<User>
```

Answer (score 1):

For search in such a way, with you entering "K" and "Kourosh" showing up, you can use a code like this:

This makes the words being searched letter by letter.

```java
public List<Bean> getWords(String englishWord) {
        if(englishWord.equals(""))
            return new ArrayList<Bean>();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + ENGLISH + " LIKE ? ORDER BY " + ENGLISH + " LIMIT 100";

        SQLiteDatabase db = initializer.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
        // this is the main thing

            cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{"%" + englishWord + "%"});

            List<Bean> wordList = new ArrayList<Bean>();
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String english = cursor.getString(1);
                String bangla = cursor.getString(2);
                String status = cursor.getString(3);
                wordList.add(new Bean(id, english, bangla, status));
            }

            return wordList;
        } catch (SQLiteException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
    }
```