# How to read DataBaseRoom and display a textView

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am practicing with dataBaseRoom, for them I have created a button, which allow me to read database , i want to put the name of a user and when pressing the button (read data base) reflects me, his name, last name and age in the texview,the problem is that I do not know how to display the data in a textView.

Activity where I want to carry out the actions

[image]

//Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)@ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val age: Int
)
```

//Dao

```
 @Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addUser(user: User)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun readAllData(): LiveData<User>
    
}
```

//DataBase

```
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class UserDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: UserDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): UserDatabase{
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if(tempInstance != null){
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this){
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    UserDatabase::class.java,
                    "user_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//Repository

```
 class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {
    
    val readAllData: LiveData<User> = userDao.readAllData()

    suspend fun addUser(user: User){
        userDao.addUser(user)
    }

}
```

//ViewModel

```
  class UserViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<User>
    private val repository: UserRepository

    init {
        val userDao = UserDatabase.getDatabase(application).userDao()
        repository = UserRepository(userDao)
        readAllData = repository.readAllData
    }

    fun addUser(user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.addUser(user)
        }
    }

}
```

I want to add my texview in this class

```
  mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)
        mUserViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

            textView1.text = it.firstName
            textView2.text = it.lastName
            textView3.text = it.age.toString()


        })
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment add an observer to the LiveData and set the TextView value within the observer.

[See the documentation here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).

---

To get the data of the latest added user in the fields, you can use this (check whether `.size` or `.length` is correct for you):

```
    mUserViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { users ->
        if (users != null) {
            for (user in users) { // I'm not sure about kotlin syntax 
                if (user.firstName == enteredFirstName &&
                             user.lastName == enteredLastname) {   
                    textViewFirstName.text = user.firstName
                    textViewLastName.text = user.lastName
                    textViewAge.text = user.age.toString()
```

Comment: I implemented it this way but it tells me that Required: CharSequence! Found: List <User>!, Look at ListFragment please.

Comment: well because `user` is of type `List<User>` .. you have to call `textViewNamw.text = user.get(0).getName()` .. replace `0` with the position of the user you want to show and `getName()` with the method you have implemented in `User`

Comment: I have implemented this method but when I put the username in the editext and press the search button, the user that I have hosted in the database does not appear, I updated  my code.

Comment: in your code you put the firstName of user[0] but then the last name of another user and the age of a third user. all three lines should have the same user reference.

Comment: Did you check with the database inspector whwther the data is actually added to the db?

Comment: Hi, something particular happens, I'm going to AddFragment, I add user data and when I try to search for a user, only the last registered user is reflected, my wish is to add a username and when I press the search button, all your information is reflected user.

Comment: @JorgeLeonardo Hey, okay I didn't understand what you tried to achieve.. Please see my update!
You basically iterate through the list of `users` that you get and check whether the name corresponds to the name that was entered in the EditText. If it matches, you set the data to the TextViews

Comment: Hi, I am trying to create a database like this one, but applying good practices with room :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxkdWX3UaNk

Comment: please observe from minute 1:21 to 3:03

Comment: @Jorge Ok. And you what should happen if there is a "Peter A" and a "Peter B" and you just look for "Peter" ? You probably want to enter both Names and then only fill the age?

Comment: if peter is not in the database with u toast it could say user not registered

Comment: @Jorge, the question is what should happen when there are TWO Peters ?? In the video you linked they do this based on `productId`, which is unique! but First Name is not unique..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224969/discussion-between-jorge-leonardo-and-tobi).

Comment: Hello, master, I made a few small changes in my code, which allows me to access the information of the first user that I have registered in my database, I only need the method that allows me to enter a username in the editext and then when you press the search button you can see your data